# How to submit data in react autosuggest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'am using react autosuggest npm package to input city name.

When the city name is selected it must be submitted and corresponding weather info must be displayed.

Below is the code for reference

#### 1. Form.js

```js
const getSuggestions = value => {
    const inputValue = value.trim().toLowerCase();
    const inputLength = inputValue.length;
  
    return inputLength === 0 ? [] : cities.filter(data =>
      data.name.toLowerCase().slice(0, inputLength) === inputValue
    ).slice(0,3);
  };
  
  const getSuggestionValue = suggestion => suggestion.name;
  
  // In the below function I get the data, but, how to submit?
  const renderSuggestion = suggestion => 
  (
  
    <table className='auto-complete'>
          <tbody>
            <ArrowTooltip title={suggestion.name + ', ' + countries.getName(suggestion.country,"en")} placement="top">
            <tr>
            <td style={{ width: '70%' }} dangerouslySetInnerHTML=
            {highlight(suggestion.name, suggestion.value)}></td>
            <td style={{ width: '30%' }}>{suggestion.country}</td>
          </tr>
            </ArrowTooltip>
          </tbody>
        </table>
  );
  
  class Form extends Component {
    constructor() {
            super();
        
            this.state = {
                value: '',
                suggestions: [] 
            };
        }
    
        onChange = (event, { newValue }) => {
            this.setState({
                value: newValue
            });
        };
    
        onSuggestionsFetchRequested = ({ value }) => {
            this.setState({
                suggestions: getSuggestions(value)
            });
            console.log('state', this.state)
        };
    
        onSuggestionsClearRequested = () => {
            this.setState({
                suggestions: []
            });
        };
    
    render() {
        const { value, suggestions } = this.state;
    
        const inputProps = {
            placeholder: 'Search City...',
            value,
            onChange: this.onChange
        };
    
        return(
            <Autosuggest
                suggestions={suggestions}
                onSuggestionsFetchRequested={this.onSuggestionsFetchRequested}
                onSuggestionsClearRequested={this.onSuggestionsClearRequested}
                getSuggestionValue={getSuggestionValue}
                renderSuggestion={renderSuggestion}
                inputProps={inputProps}
            />
        )
    }
  }
```

#### 2. App.js (Parent File)

```js
getWeather = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const city = e.target.elements.city.value;
    const country = e.target.elements.country.value;
}
```

Well here I do get the city value in `onChange`, but, how to pass country value which I get in `suggestion.country` in `renderSuggestion()` method?

Comment: in `onChange ` what is the value you're getting?

Comment: I got the answer... Thanks for response!!!